# MVC 5 Model. Set Property to Database or Entity Framework value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, properties, relationships

The model Survey CRUD's the Questions:

```
 public class Survey
    {
        public int SurveyID { get; set; }
        public string Question1 { get; set; }
        public string Question2 { get; set; }
        public string Question3 { get; set; }
        public string Question4 { get; set; }
        public string Question5 { get; set; }
    }
```

This model IntroResponse should have Properties that should be set to the values set in Survey. (IntroResponse is read only, not Creating or Editing Question properties):

```
public class IntroResponse : IValidatableObject
{
    public int IntroResponseID { get; set; }

    public int SurveyID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SurveyID")]
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }

    public string Question1 { get; set; }
    public string Question2 { get; set; }
    public string Question3 { get; set; }
    public string Question4 { get; set; }
    public string Question5 { get; set; }

    public IntroResponse()
    {
        //Code here?            
    }
```

As you can see these two models have a realtionship that is:
SurveyID 1 -----> * IntroResponse

But I want to inherit more properties from the Survey model. Is this possible without adding Controller code at all?

Shall I retrieve this information via Entity Framework or simply get values from Database?
I could not find any earlier threads about this specific question. I really looked.

Please give me an idea about what is the best practices to achieve this.

Update:
What I want to have is the Questions automatically retrieved and displayed when I select SurveyID with the dropdown. This would require client-side code, right? So should I have JavaScript code make a database call to get the Questions? I don't want to mix JavaScript and C#/Razor code in this way. That is why I am asking for some pointer!

Comment: "Shall I retrieve this information via Entity Framework or simply get values from Database?" That's essentially like asking whether you should drink water from a cup or the faucet. Either way, you're dealing with the database. Please clarify your question.

Comment: OK Well my question is about weather to write code so that EntityFramework does the work.
Or if I should write a call to database in my controller to pick up the values?

Comment: What I want to have is the Questions automatically retrieved and displayed when I select SurveyID with the dropdown. This would require client-side code, right? So should I have JavaScript code make a database call to get the Questions?

I don't want to mix JavaScript and C#/Razor code in this way. That is why I am asking for some pointer!